# scope of setTimeout 

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

Let say I have a JS code like this

```
var num = 0;

function foo(input){
   num = input;

}


function bar(){
  setTimeout(foo(2), 100);//1

  setTimeout(function(){foo(5);},100);//2

  alert("num =" + num);//3

}
```

what will be the result of using 1 and 3 .....2 and 3 ...i have  the results but don't able to understand the behavior... any help will be appreciated with  detail explanation...

Comment: The snippet is not working in IE nor Firefox. The line `setTimeout(foo(2), 100);` has error "useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)". If I surround it with quotes it does nothing: finally `num == 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an issue of "scope", but rather an issue of timing.

1. Will have a side-effect of setting `num` to 2. `foo(2)` is executed *right now* and the result (garbage) is passed to `setTimeout`. (That is, `foo(2)` is *not* run as/in the *timeout callback*.)
2. Will invoke `foo(5)` after ~100 milliseconds. The anonymous function acts as the callback which in turn invokes `foo(5)` that will have a side-effect of assigning 5 to `num`.
3. Alerts *right now*. The value will be "num = 2" because `foo(2)` ran *right now* (well, just before ;-) but `foo(5)` in the *callback* will run *at some time later* (and thus has not had a chance to set `num`).

Happy coding.